# Dynamically creating div according to number of data , equally dividing width, in a row

Tags: javascript

I have data = [1,2,3,4,5,...]

Number of data can change.

Here, I have 5 data and want to create 5 divs according to the number of data(array.length) dynamically such that width of divs are adjusted in a row equally.

Using below method:-

```
var html="";
/*
-
-
-
*/
html +="<div</div>"
```

Comment: Use `display: flex` for parent element and add `flex: 1;` to all dynamicalyl created divs.

Comment: forEach or map loop..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flex` CSS display mode. If you use jQuery, it is very easy.

```
<div style="display: flex;" id="parent"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        for (k in arr) {
            jQuery('#parent').append('<div style="flex: 1;">' + arr[k] + '</div>');
        }
    });

</script>
```

```css
.display_flex {
  display: flex; /* Important! */
}

.flex_entry {
  flex: 1; /* Important! */
  margin: 1px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="display_flex">
  <div class="flex_entry"></div>
  <div class="flex_entry"></div>
  <div class="flex_entry"></div>
</div>

<div class="display_flex">
  <div class="flex_entry"></div>
  <div class="flex_entry"></div>
  <div class="flex_entry"></div>
  <div class="flex_entry"></div>
  <div class="flex_entry"></div>
</div>
```

[More about flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Can it be done without flex? . I want to divide the row in equal according to data in array which keep changes and according to data in array, the <div> is created dynamically of equal width.

Comment: Flex is the easiest way how to do it. @ManzerAhmad

Comment: <div> are not divided equally in a row dynamically, according to your method.

Comment: @ManzerAhmad I made answer update to give you example again.